# When is the Unix Command rmdir appropiate to use?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, console

I am attempting to use the Unix Command `rmdir` to delete a directory, but I keep getting a message:

```
pwd
/Users/jona/Documents/Unix-Practice
$ rmdir Unix-Practice
rmdir: Unix-Practice: No such file or directory
```

I am also doing this to see if I need to be above the directory to be deleted:

```
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/Users/jona/Documents
$ rmdir Unix-Practice
rmdir: Unix-Practice: Directory not empty
```

Am I using the command improperly?

I am learning from this guide http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex7.html and it is telling me to use `rmdir`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your directory contain some files, when directory is empty then use `rmdir`.

[From the man page of rmdir](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/rmdir.1.php)

- *rmdir - remove empty directories*
- *Remove the DIRECTORY(ies), if they are empty.*

Use:
`rm -r Unix-Practice` to delete directory with files